# Where did the /boot/grub2/grub.cfg `linux16` lines go CentOS 8 / Oracle Linux 8 / RHEL8?

Tags: centos, fedora, redhat-enterprise-linux, centos-8

In el7 there were lines in grub.cfg like `linux16 /vmlinuz` to load a kernel and create menu items.  In el8, those menu items are not listed in grub.cfg after a `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.

I like to view the list of kernel menu items to double-check versions sometimes.

Where are they stored in el8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configurations are now in /boot/loader/entries/*
It refers to variables defined /boot/grub2/grubenv

```
[root@r8 ~]# ls /boot/loader/entries/fb10fdf8948142c6b39db90da4c74b4b-*
/boot/loader/entries/fb10fdf8948142c6b39db90da4c74b4b-0-rescue.conf                     /boot/loader/entries/fb10fdf8948142c6b39db90da4c74b4b-4.18.0-348.7.1.el8_5.x86_64.conf
/boot/loader/entries/fb10fdf8948142c6b39db90da4c74b4b-4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64.conf  /boot/loader/entries/fb10fdf8948142c6b39db90da4c74b4b-4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64.conf

[root@r8 ~]# cat /boot/grub2/grubenv
# GRUB Environment Block
saved_entry=fb10fdf8948142c6b39db90da4c74b4b-4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64
kernelopts=root=/dev/mapper/rhel_dhcp--12--213--33-root ro crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/rhel_dhcp--12--213--33-swap rd.lvm.lv=rhel_dhcp-12-213-33/root rd.lvm.lv=rhel_dhcp-12-213-33/swap rhgb quiet
boot_success=0
boot_indeterminate=2
###############################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################
```

[BootLoaderSpec](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/BootLoaderSpec/)